# Is there any way to make the pygame window follow the mouse?

Tags: python-3.x, pygame

I'm removing the frame using pygame.NOFRAME, but I still want the window to be able to be moved by dragging a better-looking bar at the top.

Comment: Pygame specifically doesn't have this (as far as I know) so you're likely going to have to go down the route of looking for OS-specific libraries for general window management to change the position.